# Influences on the accent of Georgia (the American state)?

Tags: historical-linguistics, accent, american-english

The accent of (most of) the American state of Georgia, as far as I know, lacks the drawl of most other Southern American accents. Instead, it is quicker and clipped. Does anyone know why? Does the accent have any influences (such as, from part/s of England, or other part/s of the British Isles) that other Southern accents don't?

Comment: Having lived along different borders with Georgia my whole life, I haven't noticed such a difference. Do you have an example of what you think sounds *clipped* versus one that doesn't? Georgia will have Appalachian influences in the north, and Savannah being a port city is quite unique.

Comment: The two examples of "clipped" I can think of are Jimmy Carter, and a college teacher I had from Chattanooga, Tennessee, which IIRC is just next to Georgia.


I usually associate the word "clipped" with the way upper-class Londoners sound--at least in movies and TV--and RP, or the "BBC accent." The accent I think of as "Georgian" has a similar speed and rhythm--unlike the slower drawl that I associate with both most of Appalachia and the Deep South.


(The actor Josh Holloway doesn't have what I think of as a "Georgia accent." I always guessed that he grew up fairly close to Alabama.)